# How to get NCR Ranger armor/gear in Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Iv'e been playing Fallout New Vegas and iv'e gotten quite far into the game. I'm planning on joining the NCR (which I know how to do) but I was wondering if after joining, is there anyway to get NCR Ranger armor/gear or become a NCR Ranger. I don't want to kill any of the NCR members. If there is a way to become one or get the armor/gear, how do I do that without killing any NCR members. I haven't made it to New Vegas, but I would like to be prepared for the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As seen on [the wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/NCR_Ranger_combat_armor), there are a few ways to get NCR armor:

1. With a "liked" or higher reputation with the NCR, Colonel James Hsu will give the Courier a key to the NCR Ranger Safehouse. Inside are a set of NCR salvaged power armor, NCR Ranger patrol armor, and the NCR Ranger combat armor. There is also a reloading bench and some empty foot lockers, alongside a hunting revolver, assault carbine, and trail carbine. Note that all armors are in poor condition.
2. This armor can be found on NCR Veteran Rangers throughout the game in areas occupied by the NCR (e.g. Camp Golf, the NCR Ranger Safehouse, Ranger Station Bravo, Camp Forlorn Hope, etc.) or if the Courier is labeled a terrorist by the NCR, as there will be ranger kill-squads sent to eliminate them.
3. There are several dead NCR troopers wearing this armor at the Long 15 if you choose to nuke the NCR upon completion of The Apocalypse. (Lonesome Road)

Although I'm assuming #3 doesn't apply to you so much.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Also noteworthy is you can get forgiveness from the NCR about halfway through the game. You can kill an NCR Ranger if you're a high enough level to encounter one and then meet Mr. House.